# getDevicePushTokenAsync error on bare workflow

Tags: react-native

I implemented push notification on managed workflow which is working properly but when I eject from managed workflow, I am getting error at line

```
pushToken = (await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync()).data;
```

Error: Encountered an exception while calling native method: Exception occurred while executing exported method getDevicePushTokenAsync on module ExpoPushTokenManager: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.luciajane.taskuser. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.

I passed experienceId but still getting error?

pushToken = (await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync({experienceId: "@luciajane/task-user"})).data;

Answer (score 1):

I found reason. You have to setup by making new project on firebase then download google-services.json file and add that to your expo project. As expo mentioned **Firebase Cloud Messaging is required for all managed and bare workflow Android apps made with Expo**.For setup follow this link https://docs.expo.io/push-notifications/using-fcm/

Comment: To get the `expoPushToken` Android on the bare workflow, do you have to make `expo build:android` or can it be done in `yarn run android` ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountred this error after adding the push notification while the android folder was already generated during local builds, you have to regenerate the folder agian "if no changes were made to the native code" using npx expo prebuild --clean,

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).